# Python: sorting recursive paths by filename?

Tags: python

I search for txt files recursively across subdirectories:

```
import glob


def find_recursive(path):
    files = []
    for f in sorted(glob.glob(path, recursive=True)):
        files.append(f)
    return files


if __name__ == "__main__":

    target_path = '/temp/**/*.txt'

    found_files = find_recursive(target_path)

    print(found_files)
```

This returns for example:

```
/temp/sub1/joe.txt
/temp/sub1/roy.txt
/temp/sub2/dan.txt
```

How would I sort the list of paths found, but sort by the filename?

The exepected output would be `dan, joe, roy`:

```
/temp/sub2/dan.txt
/temp/sub1/joe.txt
/temp/sub1/roy.txt
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the easiest solution is using sorted and a key like this

```py
sorted(glob.glob(path, recursive=True), key=os.path.basename)
```

Where you teel python to sort passed on the basename of the file (using os)

So your function becomes:

```py
import glob
import os

def find_recursive(path):
    return sorted(glob.glob(path, recursive=True), key=os.path.basename)
```